# Can I return a different sequences from a function?

Tags: c, function, random, time, srand

// I wrote a function that returns an array's values. The values must be 
chosen randomly. But in main function, when I call the funtion,it gives me the same values. I wanna different randomly numbers, Can I avoid it?

```
void a();

int main(){
a();
a();
return 0;
} 
void a(){
int i, b[6];
srand(time(NULL));

for(i=0; i<6; i++){
    b[i]= rand()%10 +1;
    printf("%d " , b[i]);
    if(i==5) printf("\n");
}
}
```

Comment: You say, in function a, declare a seed that is randomly chosen and use it. Right?

Comment: Use correct prototype function declarators. And the code is not standard compliant anyway, as you don't have the functions you use (`printf`, `rand`, etc.) declared.

Answer (score 2):

You should only seed the randomizer once. By seeding it twice so quickly after each other there is a large chance the time, and thus seed value, is still the same and the pseudo random number generator will return the same sequence twice.

```
void a();

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL)); //Seed only once...
    a();
    a();
    return 0;
} 

void a()
{
    int i, b[6];


    for(i=0; i<6; i++)
    {
        b[i]= rand()%10 +1;
        printf("%d " , b[i]);
        if(i==5) 
             printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void a();

int main(){
srand(time(NULL));
a();
a();
return 0;
} 
void a(){
int i, b[6];

for(i=0; i<6; i++){
    b[i]= rand()%10 +1;
    printf("%d " , b[i]);
    if(i==5) printf("\n");
}
}
```